# Get istio gateway url

Tags: kubernetes, istio, istio-gateway

Run example

```
k apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antonputra/tutorials/main/lessons/155/3-example/6-gateway.yaml
```

How to access istio gateway from localhost?

Tried

```
export INGRESS_HOST=$(kubectl get gateway  api -o jsonpath='{.status.addresses[0].value}')
export INGRESS_PORT=$(kubectl get gateway  api  -o jsonpath='{.spec.listeners[?(@.name=="http")].port}')
curl -s -I -HHost:app.devopsbyexample.com "http://$INGRESS_HOST:$INGRESS_PORT"
```

However INGRESS_HOST is empty as

```
kubectl get gateway  api -o jsonpath='{.status.addresses[0].value}'
```

empty as well

Answer (score 0):

To access an Istio Gateway from your localhost using curl, you need to set `INGRESS_HOST` and `INGRESS_PORT` variables.

The environment variables you have set doesnt contain the `<gateway name>`. Try adding the gateway name and set the variables.

```
$ export INGRESS\_HOST=$(kubectl get gateway <gateway-name\> -o jsonpath=’{.status.addresses[0].value}’

$ export INGRESS\_PORT = $(kubect get gateway <gateway-name\> -o jsonpath=’{.spec.listeners[?(@.name==”http”)].port}’
```

Replace the  with the name of your Istio gateway. These commands retrieve the external IP or domain address and the port number assigned to the Istio Gateway and set them as the values of the `INGRESS_HOST` and `INGRESS_PORT` variables respectively.

Now you can access the Istio Gateway using curl.

```
Curl -s -I -HHost:app.devopsbyexample.com "http://$INGRESS\_HOST:$INGRESS\_PORT"
```

Make sure [app.devopsbyexample.com](http://app.devopsbyexample.com) is the desired hostname or the domain that matches the routing rules defined in your Istio Gateway configuration.

By setting these variables and using curl, you can [access](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-control/#accessing-ingress-services) the Istio Gateway from your local host.

Answer (score 0):

You can access via `istio-ingressgateway`

you can get `IP & PORT` for `istio-ingressgateway` like this

```
# display gw IP  
kubectl -n istio-system get svc/istio-ingressgateway -o yaml | grep loadBalancer -A4    

# display gw http port  
kubectl -n istio-system get svc/istio-ingressgateway -o yaml | grep http2 -A4  

# display gw https port  
kubectl -n istio-system get svc/istio-ingressgateway -o yaml | grep https -A4
```

then you can use this `IP & PORT`  to access your services.

notice that you configure `gateway`, which is inter-connected via `virtualservice`
see [istio docs](https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#gateways)  for more info.